# Predicting value for mnist data set on your own test images

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, mnist

I want to predict values for my own test data in mnist data set but my code always returns the same output ( 2  always prints 2 )  below is my code
what changes should i make?

Please help, Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
from PIL import Image,ImageFilter


# Define the model (same as when creating the model file)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver.restore(sess, "testdata/model.ckpt")
    print ("Model restored.")
    imvalue = cv2.imread("zero.jpg")
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(imvalue, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #data = np.reshape(imvalue,[28,28])
    data = np.reshape(gray_image,-1)
    prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
    pint=prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [data]}, session=sess)

print (pint[0])`
```

Comment: Try printing the weights (`W.eval()`). Do they look reasonable after being restored? Is there a crazy large bias? What do the logits look like?

Comment: [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ...,
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
2   
this is how the output looks after printing weights
the last value 2 is the output of pint which I am printing and as I mentioned earlier 
i dont know why all the weights are zero plz help me to figure out what is going wrong
thankyou @Allen Lavoie

Comment: You could try [list_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/list_variables): is there a variable which matches `W.name` in the checkpoint?

Comment: [('Variable', [784, 10]), ('Variable_1', [10])]
this was the output after printing list_variables 
variable,[784, 10] is W which i have defined in model

Comment: Does it have a non-zero value if you print with [tf.train.load_variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/load_variable)?

Comment: no. All the values in the array are 0, there is no non-zero value

Comment: Then it sounds like you should initialize your weights and biases randomly and do some training before you try to make predictions.

Comment: alright how do I do that can u help? can u elaborate it? (sorry I am new and don't have much practical knowledge of tensorflow) also I have saved trained model still do i have to train it ?